# Discord.js get high resolution avatar

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Is there a way to got high resolution avatars in Discord.js/Canvas? Because If I trie to add the avatar to an image, it has a very bad quality. Is there a way to get a better quality? I have tried 
`const avatar1 = await Canvas.loadImage(message.author.displayAvatarURL({ format: 'jpg', size: '512' }));`, but It shows this error: `(node:8760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [IMAGE_SIZE]: Invalid image size: 512`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ImageURLOptions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/typedef/ImageURLOptions)'s size must be number, not string. So your code would be fixed here:

```js
const avatar1 = await Canvas.loadImage(
    message.author.displayAvatarURL(
        { format: 'jpg', size: 512 }
    )
);
```